# Api sending data from backend to frontend

Tags: laravel, api

I have made an web app where the users can question and answer. By fetching the data from database, i send the required data to frontend using JSON. Here is the controller.

```
public function addquestion(Request $request)
{
    if($request->Ajax())
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $question = new Question();
            $question->question=$request->question;
            $question->save();

            $addq_id=new QuestionUser();
            $addq_id->q_id=$question->id;
            $addq_id->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $addq_id->save();

            echo json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE,'question'=>$request->question));die;
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode('notloggedin');die;    
        }
    }       
}
```

and here is jquery and ajax:

```
$(document).on('click','.addquestion',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var question = $(this).prev().val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{url('/music/addquestion')}}",
        data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "question": question
        },

        success: function (data) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(res.status == true)
            {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else if(res == 'notloggedin')
            {
                alert('You must login first!');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

I also used the facebook api and google api for authentication. But, here i am confused on what is building your own api mean. Is my this app an api? I have read more of the articles that it is the interface between backend and frontend?

Comment: For first - remove echo and replace it with return \Response::json($data);

Comment: Your own API - is resources on your application. So,  GET/POST/PUT/DELETE on /api/objectName or every name you want

Comment: And if it's laravel >5.3 - there is API controller in it with routes, so just read docs.